# PUGJS - How do I access data from locals?

Tags: node.js, express, templates, pug

I'm trying to create a simple template using PugJS but I'm having trouble reading data from the object I passed to the renderer. This is what I have:

```
// main.js -- nodejs + expressjs

const defaultUser = { isAnonymous: true, name: 'test' };
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(pug.compileFile(__dirname + '\\views\\index.pug', defaultUser));
});
```

---

```
// index.pug -- the template I'm having trouble with

doctype html
html
    head
        if #{isAnonymous}
            title Test page
        else
            title #{name} - Test page
```

I'm getting a Syntax Error (unexpected character '#') on line 4 of the template:

```
  > 4|      if #{isAnonymous}
------------^
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to quote isAnonymous there, the line begins with "if" so it's looked at as javascript.

```
doctype html
html
    head
        if isAnonymous
            title Test page
        else
            title #{name} - Test page
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there some other website I can look at for documentation? I find the official one to be too oversimplified.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure, I'm relatively new to Pug/Jade myself so I mostly alternate between reading through all the Pug docs and banging my head against the desk.

Comment: I see, thanks! I hope brighter days are ahead for you, your head and your desk :)